# PHPUnit - Mocking specific methods of the Magento class being tested

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, phpunit

I am testing a class using PHPUnit. I want the method that I'm testing to run as normal, but I want to mock another method in this class in order to return a specific string.

My issue is that I can't seem to create a mock object without overriding the logic of the method i actually want to test.

Here is the code of the class being tested:

```
class Base_Customer_Model_Observer
{
public function addToVip($observer)
{
    if ($this->isRequestFromVipPage() == "true")
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getGroupId() != 6)
        {
            $customer->setGroupId(6);
            $customer->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('You have now been added to our VIP secret sales list');
        }
        else
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('You are already on the list!');
        }
    }
}

private function isRequestFromVipPage() {
    return Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('vip_list');
}
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
class Base_Customer_Test_Model_Observer extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case
{

public function testUserIsAddedToVipList()
{

    $mock = $this->getModelMockBuilder('customer/customer')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array('save'))
        ->getMock();

    $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('setGroupId')
            ->with(6);

    $eventObserver = new Varien_Event_Observer(array('event' => new Varien_Event(array('customer' => $mock))));

    $observer = $this->getModelMockBuilder('base_customer/vip_observer')
        ->setMethods(array('isRequestFromVipPage', 'addToVip'))
        ->getMock();

    $observer->expects($this->once())
        ->method('isRequestFromVipPage')
        ->will($this->returnValue('true'));

    $observer->addToVip($eventObserver);

}

}
```

Comment: I'm currently in the process of exploring mocks/stubs in PHPUnit so I'm not qualified to give you an answer but based on my very limited knowledge... should you be passing `addToVip` to `setMethods()` if you actually don't want to mock this method?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did try that but it seems that if I don't pass the method name to setMethods then that method won't exist at all in the mock, so i get "call to undefined method..."

Comment: I think it will. It's only when you don't pass any method at all then all the methods would get mocked by default (you'd have to pass `null` to avoid this). If you pass the method, it will get mocked for sure so your `$observer->addToVip` cannot work.

Comment: One more thing: are you actually mocking the right class? (`base_customer/vip_observer` passed to the `getModelMockBuilder()` method vs `Base_Customer_Model_Observer` which contains `addToVip()` method - that would explain the *undefined method* error when you don't mock it)

Comment: yep you're right, that was the issue. my next problem is that I need that mocked method to return 'true' and for some reason it isn't - it's now calling the addToVip method correctly, but it's not getting past that if condition

Comment: Does the `isRequestFromVipPage()` method exist in the class you are testing? Because I think you cannot mock a method which doesn't.

Comment: it does yeah. i've actually given up, moved the actual logic into a different function which gets called if the condition is true. tests all seem to work ok for that. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a partial mock (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects), and do your asserts on the partial mock instead of creating a new test object. For example:

```
$eventObserver = $this->getMock('Varien_Event_Observer',array('isRequestFromVipPage'), array('event' => new Varien_Event(array('customer' => $mock))))
```

will give you an object with only `isRequestFromVipPage` being replaced by PHPUnit. You can then configure this method to return whatever you need.